# System.AggregateException on Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, task, aggregateexception

I have the following code which is firing off a number of async Task.

```
        List<TimeoutException> TimeoutExceptions = new List<TimeoutException>();
        List<TaskCanceledException> TaskCanceledExceptions = new List<TaskCanceledException>();
        List<Exception> Exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        List<AggregateException> AggregateExceptions = new List<AggregateException>();

        List<Models.Channel.IChannel> channels = new List<Models.Channel.IChannel>();            
        channels.Add(new Models.Channel.DummyChannelName());            

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (Models.Channel.IChannel channel in channels)
        {
            try
            {
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();                    
                cts.CancelAfter(channel.TimeOut);

                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                { 
                    channel.Data = channel.RequestOffers(new Models.Request.AvailabilityRequest()).Result;

                    if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)                        
                        cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                }, cts.Token));
            }
            catch (TimeoutException t)
            {
                TimeoutExceptions.Add(t);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException tc)
            {
                TaskCanceledExceptions.Add(tc);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                AggregateExceptions.Add(ae);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Exceptions.Add(ex);
            }

        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

The problem I have is that if a task is cancelled because of a timeout I'm getting the following exception

```
<ExceptionMessage>One or more errors occurred.</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.AggregateException</ExceptionType>
```

Is it just a simple case that I need a Try Catch around Task.WaitAll, or should my code be structured differently.

Comment: Is that a problem if I have Task.WaitAll called multiple times, as it will be within my foreach loop ?  Or are you saying the Task.WaitAll should have it's own try/catch  block ?

Comment: Ah i just skimmed you code and missed the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an exception occurs inside a task the exception is raised on the calling thread when you `Wait` for a task. If a task is sucessfully created all exceptions that occur inside the task are wrapped in an `AggregateException` and thrown on the wait.

For you example this means you can remove the try/catch block within your loop and use it to wrap the `Task.WaitAll(...)` after the loop.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (Models.Channel.IChannel channel in channels)
{
    Task myTask = Task.Run(...); // create your task here
    tasks.Add(myTask);
}

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
catch
{
    // Insert Exception handling logic
}
```

Comment: I have a question... if you plop the WaitAll in a try-catch block, and you have 5-tasks.  One of five throws an exception.  Will it pop out, and not wait for the other 4 (good) tasks?  Are there other considerations in putting a WaitAll in a trycatch block